# Bash- Checking what type of files exist in directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I need function which will look for types of file extensions and will dispay it in terminal. I was experimenting with command `find` but I have no idea how to do that.

For example, this is content of my directory: `music1.mp3; music2.mp3; document.txt; movie.avi; movie2.avi; movie3.avi`.

The output should look like:

```
 Available extensions: mp3, txt, avi
```

So i don't want to have some specific extensions prepared, I want to look for all existing ones in directory

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post your code, what you already done and read [how to ask] (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you want to pass a list of extensions to this function, and it will display the files having such an extension?

Comment: As said before, this is more a unix/linux question than a programming question. The question is also not clear, so when you repost in the appropriate place, make sure you make it as clear as possible. I have a hint that what you want to achieve is probably done by [_piping_ to `grep`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401867/piping-output-to-grep), but reading it I don't even fully understand what's your objective.

Comment: @glennjackman Question edited, I hope that everything is clear now

Comment: @MaksOperlejn : What do you want to do with files without extension (`foo`), and with files where the only period is the first character (`.foo`)?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command:

```
find /path/to/your/folder/ -type f | sed -rn 's|.*/[^/]+\.([^/.]+)$|\1|p' | sort -u
```

---

On OSX, replace `-r` argument with `-E`

Comment: You saved my day Kevin! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This only reports about non-hidden filenames containing a dot:

```
declare -A ext
for f in *; do 
    e=${f##*.}
    [[ $f != "$e" ]] && ext[$e]=1
done
( IFS=,; echo "available extensions: ${!ext[*]}" )
```

This is equivalent:

```
perl -MList::Util=uniq -E '
    opendir $d, ".";
    @ext = uniq map {/([^.]+$)/} grep {/^[^.].*[.]/} readdir $d;
    say "extensions: ", join ",", @ext
'
```